# Angle brackets less than and greater symbols are converted to html code after dropdownlist item was selected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have enhanced dropdownlist (html select > option) into responsive select control using css and extending jquery.
I have encountered that select text greater than and less than symbols are displayed as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

[image]

Comment: where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are try to use this `meta` tag after you check It

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<body>
<select>
<option>&lt; 1</option>
<option>>1</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think Your Input Type don't mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Put UTF-8 encoding standard in your code.  It will help your browser to understand the symbols. And use UTF-8 code for angular brackets(<>). Then your browser will consider angular brackets as a symbol instead of considering it html opening tag symbol.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>
<body>
 <select>
   <option>&lt; 1</option>
 </select>
</body>
```

I think the above snippet will Definitely resolve your problem.

Comment: @Mike Try the UTF-8 code for right angular bracket. i.e &#12297;
It will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 symbol for left angle bracket : 〈

UTF-8 symbol for right angle bracket : 〉

Source : 
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3009/index.htm

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3008/index.htm